# Perguntas ampla demais, usuário deseja apaga-la ou reescrever, após comentário. É válido?

Tags: debate

## [Devemos usar sites pré-pontos ou iniciar do 0?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8938/devemos-usar-sites-pre-pontos-ou-iniciar-do-0?noredirect=1#comment15242_8938)

Nesse caso, na minha opnião o usuário fez uma pergunta ampla demais e com respostas baseadas em opniões. Sinalizei a mesma.

Porém o autor da pergunta, se solidarizou em ajudar. Nesse caso, o que deveríamos fazer?

- **Pedir para que ele reescrever a pergunta de forma menos ampla e mais específica?**
  Considerando que em uma pergunta dessa natureza, não dá pra ser tão específico de modo possamos tendenciar uma resposta certa. Acho que no final não resultaria em muita coisa.
- **Pedir para que ele faça a exclusão voluntariamente?**
  Até que ponto podemos pedir ou tendenciar para que o usuário faça a exclusão de uma pergunta?

Ou devemos realmente aguardar mais pessoas sinalizarem ou alguém imagina outra solução?